# Windows 10: no UAC prompt in explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, uac

When I'm trying to copy or move files to a system directory (like C:\Program Files or C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu) nothing happens instead of being prompted for access rights with the usual UAC dialog. The files are not copied/moved and there is no error message.

Here's the story behind it:
I got a new PC with Windows 10 installed. There was already a user account "user" created, but I wanted my own account "Florian" with my own name. So I created my account in Administrative Tools and added it to the Administrators group. I switched to my new account and deleted the old "user" account.

[image: User accounts]

Since then I started to setup my PC and install my programs. I tried to copy some portable programs to C:\Program Files when I noticed that I could not simply copy a directory into C:\Program Files. I expected a UAC prompt, but I only got the wait cursor for the fraction of a second and nothing happened. I cannot even delete directories from installed programs.

My user account has no permissions except "special permissions" for C:\Program Files, but as I am in the Administrators group I should be able to modify files there. I checked this with another Windows 10 installation and the permissions are the same.

[image: Directory permissions]

I get the regular UAC prompt when modifying system settings running programs "as Administrator".

Any ideas why I am not prompted for permission when copying to system folders?

Comment: Please translate the screenshots into English for us.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue but do not have TortoiseCVS installed. Also, the issue is intermittent - usually a reboot clears it up (for a time). And I found a workaround for it as well. When it is happening, if I open File Explorer, then click File > Open new window > Open new window in new process, the new process provides UAC prompts properly. Still haven't figured out the cause, though.

Answer (score 6):

After some experimenting I found the solution: [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org) installed s shell extension which in some mysterious way prevented the UAC dialog. After uninstalling TortoiseCVS it worked again. To confirm it, I installed TortoiseCVS again and the problem was back.

Unfortunately, TortoiseCVS hasn't been updated in years and even the last release candidate does not solve the problem. I guess I need another CVS client on Windows 10...

Comment: Nice find! If you want to keep Tortoise but fix the problem, you can remove the icon overlay. See my answer.

Comment: From user [Trance](http://superuser.com/users/541727/trance): It wasn't the overlays, I just repro'd on win10, and it was the TortoiseShell.dll\TortoiseShell64.dll extension.

Comment: Gov Maharaj (@trance) answered it in his show: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Back-from-the-Break-with-Cortana-in-the-Car-Oculus-Pre-Order-and-more#time=5m10s

Comment: Holy cow, this also fixes the problem of the directory conflict dialog not appearing.

Answer (score 4):

We have resolved the technical issue behind the loss of UAC prompts when using TortoiseCVS in Windows 10.

Our bug number for this issue is 6978:
http://customer.march-hare.com/webtools/bugzilla/ttshow_bug.cgi?id=6978&tt=1

The problem is resolved in CVSNT 2.8.01.6002 and later releases.

You can download the latest release here:
http://march-hare.com/cvspro/

Regards,

Arthur Barrett

Product Manager CVSNT

Answer (score 1):

As the original poster's answer noted, the problem is caused by TortoiseCVS. If you want to fix the problem but keep the program, you can remove the shell extension.

Find `Tortoiseshell64.dll` in the TortoiseCVS program files. Renaming it will cause Explorer to not be able to load it, thus fixing the problem. Alternatively, you can use Sysinternals [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to disable the shell extension and stop Explorer from even trying to load it. (It will be on the Explorer tab under one of the `ShellEx` headers.)

Comment: it is not the overlay dll: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Back-from-the-Break-with-Cortana-in-the-Car-Oculus-Pre-Order-and-more#time=5m10s

Comment: @magicandre1981 Nice link! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with TortoiseCVS on a new Windows 10 system. As I started exploring various options, I found out that this problem is no longer faced if I turn UAC completely off on the Windows 10 system.

I have done the following two changes for this purpose:

1. Setting **User Account Control Settings** to **Never Notify**
   (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off)
2. Setting **User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin
   Approval Mode** option to **Disabled** in Local Security Policy
   (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852217.aspx)

This is a workaround but it might be helpful for those people who can work with keeping UAC turned off. With this workaround, they can at least continue to use TortoiseCVS smoothly without running into this issue.