# Drag and drop (or copy/paste) into Program Files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, elevation

I would like to move a folder from Downloads into Program Files. It used to work in older Windows versions (e.g. 7), but I can't do it in Windows 10 (Version 1607).

I tried the following, it always fails silently:

- Drag and drop from one Explorer window to another
- Copy (or cut), and then paste
- Using the "Move to" button in the ribbon

The image below shows what I used to get, but no longer see. Any way to get it back? I'm not sure if this was a change in Windows 10, or if there is a problem on my side.

[image: Destination Folder Access Denied]

Comment: Have you taken ownership of the folder? Try that... :)

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: I would not like to change the ownership of a system folder (currently it is `TrustedInstaller`). I can imagine this having bad side effects. Windows also won't let me add myself to the list of users with access rights without taking ownership first. I could try to login as Administrator, and then add myself.... but that's very cumbersome, opens up a security hole, and might still damage something.

Comment: Just tested myself (user account is administrator) and I am able to drag and drop from `C:\Users\Michael Nancarrow\Downloads` to `C:\Program Files\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\`, only prompted with a UAC authorization. I mean if it's a real issue and you do not want to break permissions perhaps trial http://funduc.com/app_mover.htm

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow That is very strange, then my problem is maybe not with a change in Windows 10, but with my installation. It happens on two different PCs, though, and I don't have anything funky installed that should cause this... And thanks for the link, but it won't help me here. That tool seems to move *installed* programs, registry entries and all. However, I want to just place an install-less ("portable") program folder in Program Files.

Comment: Oops, found out that this question is a (almost) duplicate, although the problem causing program is a different one. So I posted an answer for posteriority to find, and marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the question [Windows 10: no UAC prompt in explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1022072/windows-10-no-uac-prompt-in-explorer),  in fact I had TortoiseSVN (not TortoiseCVS) installed. However, removing that did not fix the problem. I also had OpenAFS installed which was the real source.

I did not uninstall OpenAFS, but just removed the following registry key (folder):

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

It had a default value of `{5F820CA1-3DDE-11DB-B2CE-001558092DB5}` which points to OpenAFS. I'm not sure if the key is supposed to exist on a fresh windows installation, or if deleting it has any ill effects on OpenAFS or Windows, so take this with a grain of salt. But I get the UAC prompts now again!

Comment: Microsoft wants to track this issue. Please open an issue in Feedback hub and share the feedback link here so that I can send the link to them.